# How to completely reset master branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was working the whole month for an ASP.NET project and made 3 huge commits and merged them into the origin master branch. Those commits included UI changes and back-end code. But I see I don't have enough time to implement the new UI and I plan to save my local repository changes in a separate folder (changes so far), start over from the most recent commit before my changes in origin/master and then I plan to change only back-end code in a new branch without touching UI and my final step is to reset the master branch with my new branch. How do I implement this? Do I need to rebase my new branch onto the origin master?

Analyzed how to rebase a branch onto the master branch

Comment: Branch names are just labels attached to commits. You can create as many new branch names at any commits that you like. You can rename branches. Just rename you current master branch to something else and create a new branch named master at the commit where you want to commence work. Then checkout that branch. Don't reset or rebase, yet, if you don't have to. Do that later. Most likely, you'll have got more practice with Git until then.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? What's its context? Is the rest of the sentence/paragraph missing?